# Need to change list in bootstrap drop-down upon selecting radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, radio-button

Here i have a set of radio buttons and a dropdown also. I want to change the populated list in the dropdown when i'm selecting different radio buttons.

eg:
I have radio buttons as

```
    a) fruits b) vegetables
```

and the dropdown, upon selecting a) fruits should be showing:

```
    • apple
    • banana
    • orange
```

and upon selecting b) vegetables:

```
    • cabbage
    • carrot
    • onion
```

Please let me know how to write a java script for the same:

radio:

```
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-warning active">
    <input type="radio" name="eating" id="fruits" autocomplete="off" checked> FRUITS
  </label>
    <label class="btn btn-warning active">
    <input type="radio" name="eating" id="vegetables" autocomplete="off"> VEGETABLES
  </label></div>
```

dropdown:

```
    <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
dropdown list
<span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#">apple</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">banana</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">orange</a></li>
    </ul></div>
```

and the list should be replaced with:

```
    <li><a href="#">cabbage</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">carrot</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">onion</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use two different dropdown menus and always show the one whose radiobutton is active.
Therefore the radiobuttons have to call a `changeTo`-function and give the id of their related dropdown:

```
<input type="radio" name="eating" id="fruits" autocomplete="off" onchange="changeTo('dropdownmenu1');"> 
<input type="radio" name="eating" id="vegetables" autocomplete="off" onchange="changeTo('dropdownmenu2');">
```

The `changeTo` script looks like this:

```
var currentDP="dropdownmenu1";
function changeTo(id){
document.getElementById(id).classList.toggle("hidden"); // show new dropdown
document.getElementById(currentDP).classList.toggle("hidden"); // hide old dropdown
currentDP=id; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type=radio]').on('click', function () {
        var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
        var name = $(this)[0].id;
        $('.dropdown-menu').empty();
        var lst = $('.dropdown-menu');
        if (isChecked && name === "fruits") {
            lst.append('<li><a href="#">apple</a></li>');
            lst.append('<li><a href="#">banana</a></li>');
            lst.append('<li><a href="#">orange</a></li>');
        }
        if (isChecked && name === "vegetables") {
            lst.append('<li><a href="#">cabbage</a></li>');
            lst.append('<li><a href="#">carrot</a></li>');
            lst.append('<li><a href="#">onion</a></li>');
        }
    });
});
```